# i want to get row names same but we want to get depending data

Tags: mysql

**one query output**

```
"MAO"           "5"
"ADA_REGULAR"   "1"
"JDA_REGULAR"   "1"
"SR_ASST_SRC"   "2"
"SUPDT_SRC"     "1"
"AO_SRC"        "3"
"ADA_SRC"       "2"
"DDA_SEEDS"     "2"
"JDA_SEEDS"     "2"
"ADDDIR_SEEDS"  "2"
```

**second query output**

```
"MAO"           "4"
"ADA_REGULAR"   "3"
"AO Tech"       "3"
"JDA_REGULAR"   "3"
```

i **want output** like this.

```
column_name      no.of_days         no.of_days

"MAO"               "5"                    4
"ADA_REGULAR"       "1"                    3
"JDA_REGULAR"       "1"                    3
"SR_ASST_SRC"       "2"                    0
"SUPDT_SRC"         "1"                    0
"AO_SRC"            "3"                    0
"ADA_SRC"           "2"                    0
"DDA_SEEDS"         "2"                    0
"JDA_SEEDS"         "2"                    0
"ADDDIR_SEEDS"      "2"                    0
"AO Tech"            0                     3
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: and add column names to first two queries

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an union for both the output for obtain all the column name you need  and the left join this result to you query output for obtain the day for first and second ooutput

```
select t1.column_name, ifnull(t2.num_days,0), ifnull(t3.num_days,0) 
from  (
  select column_name 
  from  // your query for output 1 
  union 
  select   column_name 
  from  // your query for output 2
) t1 
left  join  (
  // your query for output 1 
  select column_name,  num_days 
  from my_table1 
)  t2 ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name
left  join  (
   // your query for output 2 
  select column_name,  num_days 
  from my_table1 
)  t3 ON t1.column_name = t3.column_name
```

Comment: is there any way to simplify the query

Comment: @Koppula   .. there is not a simplest way .. ..  because  you need  all  the column_name for both the output and this is done by the subquery with union  .. then for both the result query  you need  matching and not mathcing value  and this is done by the two subquery with left join